# C# RegularExpression Attribute constructor called once

Tags: c#, validation, resources, data-annotations

I am using data annotations to validate an emailaddress.

To show an error message when the emailaddress is not valid, I use a RESX file called ErrorMessages.

My code is like this:

```
public class EmailAdressAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public EmailAdressAttribute()
        : base(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,4})(\]?)$")
    {

        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.ValidateEmailAdress;
    }
```

When I change to language (current culture) of my asp.net mvc application while running the application, the old language is still shown.
After debugging I found out that the constructor for this attribute is only called once(when I use it for the first time ).

How is the attribute being cached ?
How can I show the correct error message from the resource file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the value of your ErrorMessage property in the constructor, how about overriding that property and reading that text from the resource at the moment it's needed?

```
public override string ErrorMessage
{
   get { return ErrorMessages.ValidateEmailAdress; }
}
```

The attribute is not something that belongs to an **instance** of the class, but to the **Type**. That's why it is constructed only once in your app's lifetime.

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked (without using the override keyword).

Comment: Good! I guessed that ErrorMessage was a property of the baseclass. Apparently it belongs to the EmailAddressAttribute class.